# How to remove duplicates in a hash in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash like so:

```
[
  {
    :lname => "Brown",
    :email => "james@intuit.com",
    :fname => "James"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  },
  {
    :lname => "Smith",
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => "Brad"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  },
  {
    :lname => "Smith",
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => "Brad"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  }
]
```

What I would like to learn how to do is how to remove a record if it is duplicate. Meaning, see how there are several "brad@intuit.com" how can I remove the duplicate records, meaning remove all the others that have an email of "brad@intuit.com".... Making email the key not the other fields?

Comment: Is the a pure Ruby hash or a hash that represents data actually in the database (say, via ActiveRecord)?

Comment: why not put validates_uniqueness_of the email field? that way even if you get duplicate stuff in your params, it won't be saved. also put the necessary error catching when saving fails.

Comment: It's being created based on a CSV list, where users can input emails to invite friends

Comment: @Corroded, can't do that bec I need to take the input and then parse and display the output to the user. The above is after the input has been parsed. I just need to take it to the next level by removing duplicates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but Rails has a method on 'Enumerable' called 'index_by' which can be handy in this case:

```
list = [
  {
    :lname => "Brown",
    :email => "james@intuit.com",
    :fname => "James"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  },
  {
    :lname => "Smith",
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => "Brad"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  },
  {
    :lname => "Smith",
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => "Brad"
  },
  {
    :lname => nil,
    :email => "brad@intuit.com",
    :fname => nil
  }
]
```

Now you can get the unique rows as follows:

```
list.index_by {|r| r[:email]}.values
```

To merge the rows with the same email id.

```
list.group_by{|r| r[:email]}.map do |k, v|
  v.inject({}) { |r, h| r.merge(h){ |key, o, n| o || n } }
end
```

Custom but efficient method:

```
list.inject({}) do |r, h| 
  (r[h[:email]] ||= {}).merge!(h){ |key, old, new| old || new }
  r
end.values
```

Answer (score 26):

In Ruby 1.9.2, `Array#uniq` will accept a block paramater which it will use when comparing your objects:

```
arrays.uniq { |h| h[:email] }
```

Comment: @AnApprentice You can use the backports gem and `require 'backports/1.9.2/array/uniq'`.

Answer (score 6):

If you're putting this directly into the database, just use `validates_uniqueness_of :email` in your model. See the [documentation for this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of).

If you need to remove them from the actual hash before being used then do:

```
emails = []  # This is a temporary array, not your results. The results are still in my_array
my_array.delete_if do |item|
  if emails.include? item[:email]
    true
  else
    emails << item[:email]
    false
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**:

This will merge the contents of duplicate entries

```
merged_list = {}
my_array.each do |item|
  if merged_list.has_key? item[:email]
    merged_list[item.email].merge! item
  else
    merged_list[item.email] = item
  end
end
my_array = merged_list.collect { |k, v| v }
```

Comment: thanks but how would this work. I don't want to lose all the other information. I want to take the hash above and remove the duplicates while retaining fname and lname.

Comment: So you actually want to _merge_ the entries with the same email address? That's different than removing duplicates, which is what you asked for.

Comment: not merge just remove any duplicate's based on a key of email. It can be unintelligent and just take the firs brad@intuit.com and then remove the rest if any duplicates based solely on the email exists.

Comment: ok my apologies. Just tried the first code snippet. It errors with "undefined method `<<' for {}:Hash"

Comment: Whoops, `emails` should be an array, not a hash. My mistake

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this (delete duplicates) is what you asked for:

```
a.sort_by { |e| e[:email] }.inject([]) { |m,e| m.last.nil? ? [e] : m.last[:email] == e[:email] ? m : m << e }
```

But I think this (merge values) is what you want:

```
a.sort_by { |e| e[:email] }.inject([]) { |m,e| m.last.nil? ? [e] : m.last[:email] == e[:email] ? (m.last.merge!(e) { |k,o,n| o || n }; m) : m << e }
```

Perhaps I'm stretching the one-liner idea a bit unreasonably, so with different formatting and a test case:

```
Aiko:so ross$ cat mergedups
require 'pp'

a = [{:fname=>"James", :lname=>"Brown", :email=>"james@intuit.com"},
     {:fname=>nil,     :lname=>nil,     :email=>"brad@intuit.com"},
     {:fname=>"Brad",  :lname=>"Smith", :email=>"brad@intuit.com"},
     {:fname=>nil,     :lname=>nil,     :email=>"brad@intuit.com"},
     {:fname=>"Brad",  :lname=>"Smith", :email=>"brad@intuit.com"},
     {:fname=>"Brad",  :lname=>"Smith", :email=>"brad@intuit.com"}]

pp(
  a.sort_by { |e| e[:email] }.inject([]) do |m,e|
    m.last.nil? ? [e] :
      m.last[:email] == e[:email] ? (m.last.merge!(e) { |k,o,n| o || n }; m) :
        m << e
  end
)
Aiko:so ross$ ruby mergedups
[{:email=>"brad@intuit.com", :fname=>"Brad", :lname=>"Smith"},
 {:email=>"james@intuit.com", :fname=>"James", :lname=>"Brown"}]
```

Comment: That's snazzy only wish I knew how it did what it's doing. For extra points a little commenting

Comment: What exactly does `.inject([])` do?

Comment: @AnApprentice: sure, no problem. `#inject` is a method in `Enumerable` which is implemented by `Array`. In this form, it loops over the array yielding a *memo* and *element* object to the block, which returns the *memo* for the next iteration. So, after the sort_by, I just compare each hash with the last one in the latest memo and merge the fields if the emails match, otherwise I just tack the element onto the end of the memo, which ultimately is what `inject` will return as the value of the expression.

Comment: @Andrew, the `[]` is the initial value of the *memo* object that my expression is accumulating. Ultimately it will be the new array with the merged hash elements and will be returned by the last "iteration" of `#inject`. `#inject` isn't hugely different from plain old `#each`, it just returns a value and also accumulates that value for you by yielding it with each element to the block as it iterates.

Comment: Yea I was looking at the doc. The craziness of that being all one line made me miss that it was calling on a block and I got really confused as to how `[]` was a symbol `:P`. Thanks for the explanation!