# Delete duplicates from a hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array like:

```
[
  #<ArtLookup ARL_ART_ID: 1248525, ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER: "4502696", ARL_KIND: 3, ARL_BRA_ID: 569, ARL_DISPLAY_NR: "4502696", ARL_DISPLAY: nil, ARL_BLOCK: 1, ARL_SORT: 1>, 
  #<ArtLookup ARL_ART_ID: 1248525, ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER: "5009285", ARL_KIND: 3, ARL_BRA_ID: 525, ARL_DISPLAY_NR: "5009285", ARL_DISPLAY: nil, ARL_BLOCK: 1, ARL_SORT: 1>,
  #<ArtLookup ARL_ART_ID: 1248525, ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER: "5016786", ARL_KIND: 3, ARL_BRA_ID: 525, ARL_DISPLAY_NR: "5016786", ARL_DISPLAY: nil, ARL_BLOCK: 2, ARL_SORT: 1>,
  ...
]
```

How can I delete duplicate values from this array of hashes?

`arr.uniq` didn't help me.

I need to delete duplicates by the `ARL_DISPLAY_NR`  field. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5208395

Comment: Those are not hashes, instead, they look like ActiveRecord results from a query. Can't you use an AR query to find only the unique/distinct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you can retrieve `ARL_DISPLAY_NR` field from an instance `art` of `ArtLookup` like this:

```rb
art[:ARL_DISPLAY_NR]
```

Then you can delete duplicates according to `ARL_DISPLAY_NR` field by:

```rb
hash_array = [ artLookup_foo, artLookup_bar, ... ]

# this will keep the last one in a group of duplicates
Hash[ hash_array.map{|h| [h[:ARL_DISPLAY_NR], h]} ].values

# or keep the first one
Hash[ hash_array.reverse.map{|h| [h[:ARL_DISPLAY_NR], h]} ].values
```

However, it doesn't guarantee to keep the original order in the previous array.

Answer (score 0):

This is not what a hash is meant to be used for, you will likely end up with a `O(n)` complexity to accomplish that. Requiring to do that might signal that you have a design problem in your model.

That said, you can use something like:

```
hash = {key1: 'val1', key2: 'val2', key3: 'val3', repkey: 'val1'}
uniquevalues = {}
hash.each do |key, value|
  uniquevalues[value] = key
end
```

to get the unique values.

{"val1"=>:repkey, "val2"=>:key2, "val3"=>:key3}

Comment: give code, with model all is ok! it's is test-like app