# Display one model name when duplicate in filter form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, filter

I have this filter here for sign name. What I want to do is if I have more than one name of the sign to remove the others [image]

Check the image attached. I have two serfer names. I want to display just one

Please help me on this! Thanks

```
<div class="categories">
      <% @oferta.each do |o| %>
        <ul class="cat">
          <li class="pull-left"><h2><%= link_to o.offer,o %></h2><br><h4><%= o.description %></h4>
            <div class="main">
              <% if o.sigs.exists? %>
                <div id="myBtnContainer">
                  <button class="btn active"  onclick="filterSelection('o')">All</button>
                  <% for item in o.sigs %>
                    <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= item.name %>')"><%=  item.name%><br></button>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
                <div class="row">

                  <% for item in o.sigs %>
                    <div class="column <%= item.name %>">
                      <div class="content">
                        <%= image_tag item.image.url(), style: "width:100%"%>
                        <h4><br><%=link_to item.name,item %></h4>
                        <p><%= item.comment %></p>    
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  <% end %><br><br>
                </div>
              <% end %><br>
            </div>
          <% end %>
</div>
```

here is oferta_controller.rb

```
class OfertaController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_ofertum, only: [:destroy,:edit,:update,:show]
  def new
    @ofertum= Ofertum.new
  end

  def create
    @ofertum= Ofertum.new(ofertum_attributes)
    if @ofertum.save
      redirect_to oferta_path, notice: "Thank you... Your offer was created successfully."
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Please correct the form"
      redirect_to new_ofertum_path
    end
  end
  def index
    @oferta = Ofertum.all
  end

  def show
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
    @sig = @ofertum.sigs.build
  end
  private
  def ofertum_attributes
    ofertum_attributes = params.require(:ofertum).permit([:offer,:description,:sign,:place,:sig])
  end
  def find_ofertum
    @ofertum = Ofertum.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

in oferta model

```
class Ofertum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sigs
end
```

in sig model

```
class Sig < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ofertum
end
```

Comment: Is `item` in a hash? If so, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208344/how-to-remove-duplicates-in-a-hash-in-ruby-on-rails).

Comment: Why don't you just change the model (`oferta`) to return unique `sigs` from the controller?

Comment: @nicodp how? please explain more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if o.sigs.exists? %>
                <div id="myBtnContainer">
                 <button class="btn active"  onclick="filterSelection('o')">All</button>
                    <% o.sigs.pluck(:name).uniq.each do |name| %>
                  <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= name %>')"><%= name %><br></button>
              <% end %>
```

Here is the answer for my question to make a loop by adding this pluck(:name).uniq

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, create a new `@sigs` variable that holds all the `sigs`, so

```
@sig_names = []
@sigs_names = Ofertum.all.each do |ofertum|
  ofertum.sig.each do |sig| 
    @sig_names << sig.name
  end
end
```

Edit, there is probably a nicer way to retrieve this, but I can't think rn :D

And use this to create the filter bar.
So instead of doing the for loop inside the @oferats, iterate over @sig_cards, to generate the search bar.
Then in a second loop normally iterate over `@ofertas` to create the cards.

Remove this part of your code

```
<% if o.sigs.exists? %>
    <div id="myBtnContainer">
      <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('o')">All</button>
         <% for item in o.sigs %>
           <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= item.name %>')"><%=  item.name%><br></button>
         <% end %>
   </div>
```

And do this instead:

```
<div id="myBtnContainer">
   <button class="btn active"  onclick="filterSelection('o')">All</button>
      <% @sig_names.each do |sig_name| %>
         <button class="btn"  onclick="filterSelection('<%= sig_name %>')"><%=  sig_name %><br></button>
       <% end %>
</div>
```

Also, you use for loops in your code, which works perfectly fine, it's just not very idiomatic to ruby. `.each` is much more.

Comment: I did this but I  got this error PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "sigs" does not exist LINE 1: SELECT "sigs" FROM "oferta" ^ : SELECT "sigs" FROM "oferta"    def

Comment: Well is sigs not a column in your Ofertum table? Is it an extra table?

Comment: Here is the ofertum model class Ofertum < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sigs
end

Comment: @oferta = Ofertum.all.pluck(:sign).distinct
undefined method `distinct' for ["", "", nil, nil]:Array

Comment: Ah, ok, so you need to iterate over all the sigs and then get their names. I adapted the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I change anything in the index page? because nothing happen

Comment: Yes, of course. Instead of iterating inside the loop of oferta, you should have a
loop before where you. I will adapt my answer again, give me a minute

Comment: I added it. So loop over `@sig_names` to create the filter bar.
And after that loop over `@ofertas` as you did before to create the cards :)

Comment: Can you include in your answer how to loop over sig_names in the filter bar!

Comment: There you go.I added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197666/discussion-between-nourza-and-clara).